# Insert batch rows from file to cassandra

Tags: linux, database, bash, cassandra

I have a `.cql` file that contains some `INSERT` query, when i run it using

```
cqlsh -f cassandra.cql
```

it insert the first one and give me a error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/share/dse/resources/cassandra/bin/cqlsh", line 2385, in 
>       main(*read_options(sys.argv[1:], os.environ))
>     File "/usr/share/dse/resources/cassandra/bin/cqlsh", line 2377, in main
>       shell.cmdloop()
>     File "/usr/share/dse/resources/cassandra/bin/cqlsh", line 918, in cmdloop
>       line = self.get_input_line(self.prompt)
>     File "/usr/share/dse/resources/cassandra/bin/cqlsh", line 887, in get_input_line
>       self.lastcmd = self.stdin.readline()
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 672, in readline
>       return self.reader.readline(size)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 527, in readline
>       data = self.read(readsize, firstline=True)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 474, in read
>       newchars, decodedbytes = self.decode(data, self.errors)
>   UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 54: ordinal not in range(128)

and does not insert the rest queries

what is the problem and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What it sounds like is that you have some data for an ascii field that contains non-ascii characters.  To fix this you should check to see if any of the columns you declare for your tables are of type 'ascii' and change them to 'text' or 'varchar', both of which support unicode characters.   Either that or you need to identify the data that contains non-ascii characters and remove the non-ascii characters.